# Ajax setRequestHeader is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, jquery

I am trying to add header to ajax request.

I use **setRequestHeader** but it do nothing. I can look in firefox that request headers doesnot contains Authentication! What i am doing wrong?

And how to add header?

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: "http://test/test.svc/news",
       dataType: "json",
       beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password))
       },
       success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
       },
       error: function() {
        alert("Loading data error...");
       }
      });
     }
```

Comment: You've an extra `}` at the end. Is that a typo? Also, is `Base64` call working?

Comment: calls created without problems.  And i tryed without base xhr.setRequestHeader("test","test"); and nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try username and password instead

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: "http://test/test.svc/news",
       dataType: "json",
       username: 'username', /* not user */
       password: 'pass',
       success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
       },
       error: function() {
        alert("Loading data error...");
       }
      });
     }
```

> username - 
>   A username to be used in response to an HTTP access authentication request

Comment: @Evgeny: it's probably Firefox's protection... maybe?

Comment: In other browsers same problem

Comment: xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() return null

Comment: it's `username: "user"` not `user:...`